# Financial Investment timeline

Tags: education, finance

I am having trouble understanding on how I should answer this question and write out a timeline for it.

An investor Invests £2000 now and an extra £1500 in 2 years from now. What is the total of his investment after 4 years. Write a timeline to support this
(The interest rate is 4% per annum compounding quarterly)

Any help on understanding would be greatly appreciated .

Comment: How much is the investment worth at the beginning of this year? the end of this year? the beginning of the second year? the end of the second year? the beginning of the third year? and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quarterly rate is $0.01$ and the number of quarters are $16$ for the $2000$ and $8$ for $1500$

For the first $2000$  the investor gets $$2000(1+.01)^{16} = 2345.157290$$
For the $1500$  he/she gets $$1500(1+.01)^8 = 1624.285058$$

The total investment is $$3969.442348 \approx 3969$$

Answer (score 0):

"Write a timeline" suggests a spreadsheet to me.  Make a line for every quarter with the balance listed.  Start with $2000$, multiply by $1.01$, and add in the $1500$ at the appropriate line.  Your output would look something like
$$\begin {array}{r r}Q1&2000\\Q2&2020\\Q3&2040.20 \end {array}$$
and keep going.  You should state these are the balances at the beginning of each quarter and add one more line to get the end of $Q16$.